# Uncheck a checkbox when another is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, checkbox

```
function uncheck() {
  var notTest = document.getElementById("choice_31_3_2");
  var Test = document.getElementById("choice_31_3_1");

  if (notTest.checked) {
    Test.checked = false;
  }
  if (Test.checked) {
    notTest.checked = false;
  }
}

jQuery("#choice_31_3_1").click(uncheck);
jQuery("#choice_31_3_2").click(uncheck);

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    

<input name="input_3.1" value="Test" id="choice_31_3_1" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice_31_3_1" id="label_31_3_1">Test</label>
<input name="input_3.2" value="notTest" id="choice_31_3_2" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice_31_3_2" id="label_31_3_2">notTest</label>
```

I wrote a function to uncheck a checkbox if another one is checked, I am using jQuery to call uncheck() on those specific input.

I am getting the result I want. When I check test then check notTest, Test is being unchecked. BUT when I am pressing Test again, the test checkbox is refusing to check unless I manually uncheck notTest.

I included the code snippet , please can figure out what is wrong ?

The code is running normally on Wordpress but unfortunately not here.

Comment: `"message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'",` - your code snippet is not executable, don't make it a code snippet - or remove the HTML in the javascript panel

Comment: Do you know why this SyntaxError came up, Advice taken, snippet removed

Comment: because you put `<script>` in the javascript box

Comment: ok, thank you next time i won't when i am using online js editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BUT when i am pressing Test again, the test checkbox is refusing to
>   chech unless i manually uncheck notTest.

It is because when you press again, **you didn't check which checkbox you have clicked on**. *You simply unchecked a checked-checkbox*.

Try this simple approach

```js
var allIds = [ "choice_31_3_1", "choice_31_3_2" ];
function uncheck( event ) 
{
   var id = event.target.id;
   allIds.forEach( function( id ){
      if ( id != event.target.id )
      {
         document.getElementById( id ).checked = false;
      }
   });
}

jQuery("#choice_31_3_1").click(uncheck);
jQuery("#choice_31_3_2").click(uncheck);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input name="input_3.1" value="Test" id="choice_31_3_1" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice_31_3_1" id="label_31_3_1">Test</label>
<input name="input_3.2" value="notTest" id="choice_31_3_2" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice_31_3_2" id="label_31_3_2">notTest</label>
```

Comment: Thank you gurvinder for the solution ,and explanation

Answer (score 3):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input_3.1" value="Test" id="choice_31_3_1" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice_31_3_1" id="label_31_3_1">Test</label>
<input name="input_3.2" value="notTest" id="choice_31_3_2" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice_31_3_2" id="label_31_3_2">notTest</label>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The `if` statement is redundant. will always be true.

Comment: @guymograbi `if` statement is not redundant, Check the console now, I've edited the answer for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can code like this,

```
 HTML:- 
 <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
 <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
 <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
 <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
 JQUERY:- 
 $('input.example').on('change', function() {
     $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
 });
```

Working Demo [url](http://jsfiddle.net/MQM8k/1691/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you Sunil for the solution , I just want 2 checkboxes out of 5 not all of them, I would have used a radio button, i want the user to choose multiple checkboxes but he can not specifically choose between 2 specific ones, so i need to work on id not class

Comment: Sorry but the demo you've provided has nothing common with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
$('input.test').on('change', function() {
    $('input.test').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="input_3.1" value="Test" id="choice_31_3_1" type="checkbox" class="test">
<label for="choice_31_3_1" id="label_31_3_1">Test</label>
<input name="input_3.2" value="notTest" id="choice_31_3_2" type="checkbox" class="test">
<label for="choice_31_3_2" id="label_31_3_2">notTest</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/o7dft84Cm4tA3GUOLt4y?p=preview

```
 function uncheck() {
    if (this.checked){ // support unchecking
     $('input').prop('checked',false);
     this.checked = true
    }
  }
```

You have to know which element triggered the event in order to solve it properly.

One way to solve it is the function I show above - simply mark all checkboxes to false, then mark `this` - the element that triggered the event - to true.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS: Change your function to this:

```
$(function(){
 function uncheck(e) {
    var isElemChecked = e.target.checked;

    // Return if the element was being unchecked
    if(!isElemChecked){
      return;
    }

    $('input').prop('checked',!isElemChecked);
    $(e.target).prop('checked',isElemChecked);
  }

jQuery("#choice_31_3_1").click(uncheck);
jQuery("#choice_31_3_2").click(uncheck);
})
```

Using CSS (no need for JS code):
Change your inputs to `type=radio` and update the css as

```
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;    /* Firefox */
}

<input name="input_3" value="Test" id="choice_31_3_1" type="radio">
<label for="choice_31_3_1" id="label_31_3_1">Test</label>
<input name="input_3" value="notTest" id="choice_31_3_2" type="radio">
<label for="choice_31_3_2" id="label_31_3_2">notTest</label>
```

Please note CSS approach would not work on IE.